# Ionic Inapp browser office 365 login redirection , not firing loadstop event on redirection

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, office365, inappbrowser

I am implementing Keycloack login (Outlook-365 auth) to get user profile information

**Web app**

If i open the url(https://myurl.com/login_new.php) it works properly ,open the microsoft https://login.microsoft (login window) and after entering 
returns the user profile information.

**Mobile app**

same i need to do in mobile app using inappbrowser . I have written the following script.
It open  https://myurl.com/login_new.php and redirect to https://login.microsoft (login window)

On login window after entering username and password it stucks with disabled login button.Nothing happens.
but after app pause and resume activity it opens another window and gives the user information
(why it works only after device(app) pause and resume) ? what i am doing wrong ?

**Here is my script:**

Here in script after redirection to https://login.microsoft url after entering username and password
**browser loadstart** event fired but **loadstop** event not fired.

Kindly guide how to fix this issue.

```js
    import { InAppBrowser,InAppBrowserOptions } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

    constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser){} 

    keyclockSocialLogin(){
        const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
            zoom: 'no',
            location:'yes',
            hardwareback: 'no',
            clearcache: 'yes',
            clearsessioncache: 'yes'
        }

        var browser =  this.iab.create('https://myurl.com/login_new.php', '_blank', options);
        browser.on("loadstart").subscribe((event) => {
            console.log(event);
        });

        browser.on("loaderror").subscribe((event) => {
            alert('load error');
        });

        browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
            browser.show();
            browser.executeScript({ code: "localStorage.setItem( 'username', '' );" });
            var loop = setInterval(function() {
                browser.executeScript({
                    code: "localStorage.getItem('username');"
                }).then(values => {
                    var name = values[ 0 ];
                    if ( name ) {
                        clearInterval( loop );
                        browser.close();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        browser.on('exit').subscribe(event => {
            console.log('exit called');
        });

    }
```